How to inject service dependencies in a Factory Method while passing custom parameters in Laravel?
I would like to create a service using the factory method design pattern. So I created the following product:
class ActivityReport
{
    private $activityService;

    public function __construct(Customer $customer, ActivityService $activityService)
    {
        $this->activityService = $activityService;
    }

    public function getData()
    {
        // It will be more code
        return $this->activityService->getAll($this->customer->id);
    }
}

And I'm calling it in this way:
class ActivityReportCreator extends ReportCreator
{
    private $customer;

    function __construct(Customer $customer)
    {
        $this->customer = $customer;
    }

    public function generate() {
        $activity = new ActivityReport($customer->id);
        return $activity->getData();
    }
}

The issue here is with the constructor in the product, which accepts a service via DI (Dependency Injection) that should be automatically loaded, as it typically happens with services or controllers. The activityService has been registered and works, for example, in controllers. I can run it using app(ActivityReport::class), but first of all, I would still need to pass the $customer object not to the constructor, but to the method. Secondly, I want to consistently reference the service everywhere, just like it's done in the case of controllers.
How can I achieve this?

If you want to persist the service, I think your function should not be bound to a specific service instance. Since the function getData() needs to determine its behavior based on $customer->id, you need to pass a specific service instance rather than an abstract object. In summary, if you want to persistently reference the service, your service should be an abstract object, not an instance.
Maybe you can try getData($customerId).
